# Bertrand's paradox (statistics)

Tags: probability, paradoxes

I just learned about [Bertrand paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_%28probability%29) in today's class, and am very shocked. I was wondering if there are indeed only 3 (known?) unique ways of picking a chord in a circle at random, with 3 different probability values for the lengths being shorter than a side of an inscribed equilateral triangle, or whether there are infinitely many unique ways of picking a random chord in a circle of this length (and consequently infinitely many unique probabilities corresponding to each random picking method [countably/uncountably infinite then?]). Thanks!

Comment: another way:to select a chord of random length varying from 0 to 2r.
favorable selection length varies from 1.7r(length of side) to 2r.
so probability~2r-1.7r/2r=3/20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are infinitely many different ways to randomly pick a chord from a circle. One way to construct infinitely many would be to create a probability distribution defined over the circle and pick two points accordingly, of which there are infinitely many. However, not all of these seem "natural" like the 3 in Bertrand's paradox, which is what makes it interesting.

Comment: thanks, are there countably or uncountably infinitely many ways to pick it then?

Comment: @cantlogin: there are uncountably many ways, but only countably many which can be defined in a finite number of characters from a finite alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle "inside" the letter V, so that the top of the circle is level with the top tips of the V, and the circle does not intersect the V.

Draw a random chord by choosing a random point on the V (assume the points are uniformly distributed) and connecting this point to the top of the circle.

Let P = probability that the chord's length is longer than the side length of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the circle.

By changing the shape of the V (making it wider or taller), P can be any value between 0 and 1.